# Activating Data Interoperability extension in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, installation, data-interoperability

[image]

How to solve this problem. I have installed arcgis 10.3 and installed the extensions as well but the extension does not get activated and shows following error.

Comment: For further information, what operating system are you using?

Comment: I found the same error reported here (in Russian): http://esri-cis.ru/support/forum/?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=3&TID=274&TITLE_SEO=274-ustanovka-data-interpobility but Bing translating suggests no solution.  I think you should uninstall/reinstall to be sure that nothing went astray the first time.  If that does not resolve it, and if the "classified sensor capabilities" that it refers to mean nothing to you then I think you should submit this one to your local Esri support.